# Issue in clojure-maven-plugin 1.3.10

Tags: maven, clojure

How to give the order of compile of clojure files from "clojure-maven-plugin"?

I thought it should automatically get the order and if there is some cyclic dependency it throws cyclic-dependency exception.

My issue is when I cloning the project from git it build successful sometimes and sometimes it fails. When I going through the logs I saw that two different classes were selected to compile first in each project by that plugin.

In the failure one throws null-pointer exception which there is some .class file is not there because that class should be created before the current one.

Comment: Can you give the github address or is it an internal project?

Comment: Sorry its an internal project. I'll try some sample to give you. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

The order in the reactor of Maven will automatically be ordered into correct order but if there is a cyclic dependency than neither Maven nor any other build is able to handle that.

Comment: I do not get any cyclic dependency exception but sometimes project is failed and sometimes it is successful. I got md5sum in two directories and it was also same. Is there any effect from operating system? I use Fedora 16.